# How can I use multiple preload scripts for different Electron windows when using electron forge with the webpack template?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, electron, electron-forge

I use the [typescript+webpack template](https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-+-webpack-template) from [electron forge](https://www.electronforge.io/).

For loading **a single** preload script with webpack, there is a constant called [`MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY`](https://www.electronforge.io/config/plugins/webpack#renderer-processes) that can be set from the `package.json`, for example like so: [`"preload": { "js": "myPreload.ts" }`](https://www.electronforge.io/config/plugins/webpack#plugin-configuration). This constant is then somehow resolved from within the [Electron Forge - Webpack Plugin](https://www.electronforge.io/config/plugins/webpack) depending on whether the application is run in debug or release mode.

I have this set up, and it works fine if you have single or multiple windows that share the same `preload.ts` script. However, I can not figure out how I could specify multiple different preload scripts for other windows.

How can I use multiple different `preload.ts` scripts (for different windows) with the electron forge webpack plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is pretty simple to add multiple scripts, but as I have not seen this documented anywhere I will answer my own question here. The `name` field of the config is important, because the name in uppercase will be the prefix of the webpack constant, (e.g. `"name": "my_name"` will lead to the constant beeing called `MY_NAME_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY`.

If you now want to add multiple preload scripts you will have to add multiple entry points to which you can then refer by their names. Unfortunately each entry point also requires the `html` and `js` fields, but if you do not need those you can create empty files with the correct extension and point to these).

Here is an example to better illustrate these points:

```json
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "plugins": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
          "config": {
            "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
            "renderer": {
              "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
              "entryPoints": [
                {
                  "name": "main_window",
                  "html": "./src/main_window/index.html",
                  "js": "./src/main_window/index.js",
                  "preload": {
                    "js": "./src/main_window/preload.js"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "name": "extra_preload_main_window",
                  "html": "./src/empty.html",
                  "js": "./src/empty.js",
                  "preload": {
                    "js": "./src/main_window/preload2.js"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "name": "second_window",
                  "html": "./src/second_window/index.html",
                  "js": "./src/second_window/index.js",
                  "preload": {
                    "js": "./src/second_window/preload.js"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Which will then give you these (relevant) constants:

```js
// Path to renderer of main window.
declare MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY;

// Path to first preload script (of main window).
declare MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY;

// Path to the second preload script (of the main window).
declare EXTRA_PRELOAD_MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY;

// Preload and renderer scripts for other window.
declare SECOND_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY;
declare SECOND_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY;
```

Technically you will of course also get

```js
declare EXTRA_PRELOAD_MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY;
```

but it points to an empty file / webpack output.